# How to find the average of multiple columns using a common column in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, mean

How to calculate the mean value of all the columns with 'count' column.I have created a dataframe with random generated values in the below code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,10)*100/10).astype(int)
df

output:  

    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
0   4   3   2   8   5   0   9   9   0   5
1   1   5   8   0   5   9   8   3   9   1
2   9   5   1   1   3   2   6   3   8   3
3   4   0   8   1   7   3   4   2   8   8
4   9   4   8   2   7   9   7   8   9   7
5   1   0   7   3   8   6   1   7   2   0
6   3   6   8   9   6   6   5   0   8   4
7   8   9   9   5   3   9   0   7   5   5
8   5   5   8   7   8   4   3   0   9   9
9   2   4   2   3   0   5   2   0   3   0
```

I found mean value for a single column like this.How to find the mean for multiple columns with respect to count in pandas.

```
df['count'] = 1
print(df)
df.groupby('count').agg({'A':'mean'})


   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  count
0  4  3  2  8  5  0  9  9  0  5      1
1  1  5  8  0  5  9  8  3  9  1      1
2  9  5  1  1  3  2  6  3  8  3      1
3  4  0  8  1  7  3  4  2  8  8      1
4  9  4  8  2  7  9  7  8  9  7      1
5  1  0  7  3  8  6  1  7  2  0      1
6  3  6  8  9  6  6  5  0  8  4      1
7  8  9  9  5  3  9  0  7  5  5      1
8  5  5  8  7  8  4  3  0  9  9      1
9  2  4  2  3  0  5  2  0  3  0      1



        A
  count 
    1   4.6
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: There is no expected output.The mean value should be calculated for all 10 columns by adding all rows values and dividing by count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need `mean` of all columns per groups by column `count` use:

```
df.groupby('count').mean()
```

If need `mean` by all rows (like grouping if same values in `count`) use:

```
df.mean().to_frame().T
```